# executing a jtable shows exception

Tags: jdbc, jtable, resultset, defaulttablemodel

i am trying to develop a jtable based JDBC program that creates a table relating to the table present inside database.i have created 2 methods as databaseHandler() and graphicsHandler() to handle database and graphics related instructions.The coldata and rowdata contain column names and the resultSet rowdata.But when using these values to draw the table,i'm facing a NullPointerException but i cant understand why.Any help from anyone is most appreciated.Thank you.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Final {
    int columnno,rowno;
    Connection connection;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    ResultSetMetaData metaData;
    Vector<String> coldata;
    Vector<Object> rowdata,temp;

    DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    JTable table;

    public Final() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        ValueHolder holder = DatabaseHandler();
        GraphicsHandler(holder.getCd(),holder.getRd());
    }
    private void GraphicsHandler(Vector<String> coldata, Vector<Object> rowdata) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 20));  //setting up horizontal and vertical gap
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowdata,coldata);
        table = new JTable(tableModel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
    private ValueHolder DatabaseHandler() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company?user=username&password=password";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from product");
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
            columnno = metaData.getColumnCount();
            rowno = 1;
            coldata = new Vector<String>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnno; i++) {
                coldata.add(metaData.getColumnLabel(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
            rowdata = new Vector<Object>() ; temp = new Vector<Object>();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnno; i++) {
                    temp.add(resultSet.getString(i));
                }
                rowdata.add(temp.clone());
                temp.clear();
                rowno++;
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ValueHolder(rowdata, coldata);   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Final();
    }

}
class ValueHolder {

    Vector<Object> rd; Vector<String> cd;
    public ValueHolder(Vector<Object> rowdata, Vector<String> coldata) {
        this.rd = rowdata;
        this.cd = coldata;
    }
    public Vector<Object> getRd() {
        return rd;
    }

    public Vector<String> getCd() {
        return cd;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

I did it just by extending the javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel and adding the ability to run a query against a DB. Once this works fine, you can simply use a JTable within your Swing project.  Hope this helps.

```
/*
  this is a dynamic JTable created out of a SQL-Query 
  it can by called by  different constructors:
  - by a javax.sql.Connection
  - by a JDBC-Driver and the connection URL

 once instatiated without any error, you call the methode excuteQuery(String sqlquery) it will create the JTable and fill it with
 the result of the query

 to display this query add the JTable to a JPanel like

JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Query Result");
frame.getContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JdbcTable table = new JdbcTable(connection);
table.executeQuery("select * from employee");

frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,new JScrollPane(table)); 
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);


*/

package test;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class JdbcTable extends AbstractTableModel {

private Connection con = null;
private Statement stmt = null;
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("test");
private boolean connectionEstablished;
private String[] columnNames;
private String[] fieldNames;
private int[] columnTypes;
private ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
private Vector rows;
private int counter;
private boolean standalone = false;
private String SQLError;
private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
private SimpleDateFormat sdt;
private int maxRows = 10000;
private String nullTxt;
private boolean useNullTxt = true;

/*
 instantiate JdbcTable with a java.sql.Connection
 */
public JdbcTable(Connection con) {
    setNullTxt("NULL");
    setCon(con);
    setCounter(0);
    try {
        setStmt(con.createStatement());
    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
        logSqlException("JdbcTable(Connection con)", Level.WARNING, sqlex);
        setConnectionEstablished(false);
    }
}


/*
  instantiate JdbcTable by a JDBC-Driver and an URL
 */
public JdbcTable(String jdbcDriver, String jdbcUrl) {
    setNullTxt("NULL");
    setCounter(0);
    try {
        Class.forName(jdbcDriver);
        setCon(DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl));
        setConnectionEstablished(true);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        logException("JdbcTable(String jdbcDriver, String jdbcUrl)", Level.SEVERE, "can not load drvier class " + ex.getMessage());
        setConnectionEstablished(false);
    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
        logSqlException("JdbcTable(Connection con)", Level.WARNING, sqlex);
        setConnectionEstablished(false);
    }
}

/*
  close the Statement and the connection, use with care not to close your connection by fault

 */
public void close() {
    try {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
        logSqlException("close() ", Level.WARNING, sqlex);
    }
}

/*
  execute the query if a connection exists
  @param query the SQL statement to be run
 */
public boolean executeQuery(String query) {
    if (!isConnectionEstablished()) {
        return false;
    }


    sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    sdt = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getTimeInstance();

    Timestamp timestamp = null;
    Time time = null;
    java.sql.Date date = null;

    try {
        // we send the query to the DB
        ResultSet rs = getStmt().executeQuery(query);

        // then we need the ResultSetMetaData
        setRsmd(rs.getMetaData());

        // we loop the result and add each row to the Vector
        rows = new Vector();
        setCounter(0);
        while (rs.next()) {

            // this is just one Line
            Vector newRow = new Vector();

            // thanks to the ResultSetMetaData, we now the number of columns
            for (int i = 1; i <= getColumnCount(); i++) {

                // Depending on the Type, we add every single value
                int type = columnTypes[i - 1];
                switch (type) {
                    case Types.ARRAY:
                        newRow.add(rs.getArray(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.BIGINT:
                        newRow.add((Long) rs.getLong(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.BINARY:
                        newRow.add((String) "BINARY not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.BIT:
                        newRow.add(rs.getBoolean(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.BLOB:
                        newRow.add((String) "BLOB not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.BOOLEAN:
                        newRow.add(rs.getBoolean(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.CHAR:
                        newRow.add((String) rs.getString(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.CLOB:
                        newRow.add((String) "CLOB not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.DATALINK:
                        newRow.add((String) "DATALINK not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.DATE:
                        newRow.add((java.sql.Date) rs.getDate(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.DECIMAL:
                        newRow.add((java.math.BigDecimal) rs.getBigDecimal(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.DISTINCT:
                        newRow.add((String) "DISTINCT not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.DOUBLE:
                        newRow.add((Double) rs.getDouble(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.FLOAT:
                        newRow.add((Float) rs.getFloat(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.INTEGER:
                        newRow.add((Integer) rs.getInt(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.JAVA_OBJECT:
                        newRow.add((String) "JAVA_OBJECT not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
                        newRow.add((String) rs.getString(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.LONGVARBINARY:
                        newRow.add((String) "LONGVARBINARY not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
                        newRow.add((String) rs.getString(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.NCHAR:
                        newRow.add((String) rs.getString(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.NCLOB:
                        newRow.add((String) "NCLOB not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.NULL:
                        newRow.add((String) "NULL Type not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.NUMERIC:
                        newRow.add((java.math.BigDecimal) rs.getBigDecimal(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.NVARCHAR:
                        newRow.add((String) rs.getString(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.OTHER:
                        newRow.add((String) "OTHER Type not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.REAL:
                        newRow.add((Float) rs.getFloat(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.REF:
                        newRow.add((String) "REF Type not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.REF_CURSOR:
                        newRow.add((String) "REF_CURSOR Type not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.ROWID:
                        newRow.add((String) "ROWID Type not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.SMALLINT:
                        newRow.add((Integer) rs.getInt(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.SQLXML:
                        newRow.add((String) rs.getString(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.STRUCT:
                        newRow.add((String) "STRUCT Type not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.TIME:
                        //newRow.add((java.sql.Time) rs.getTime(i));
                        time = rs.getTime(i);
                        if (time != null) {
                            newRow.add((String) sdt.format(time.getTime()));
                        } else {
                            newRow.add((String) getNullTxt());
                        }
                        break;
                    case Types.TIMESTAMP:
                        //newRow.add((java.sql.Timestamp) rs.getTimestamp(i));
                        // because JTable does format Timestmap as Date
                        timestamp = rs.getTimestamp(i);
                        if (timestamp != null) {
                            newRow.add((String) sdf.format(timestamp.getTime()));
                        } else {
                            newRow.add((String) getNullTxt());
                        }
                        break;
                    case Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE:
                        //newRow.add((java.sql.Timestamp) rs.getTimestamp(i));
                        timestamp = rs.getTimestamp(i);
                        if (timestamp != null) {
                            newRow.add((String) sdf.format(timestamp.getTime()));
                        } else {
                            newRow.add((String) getNullTxt());
                        }
                        break;
                    case Types.TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE:
                        //newRow.add((java.sql.Time) rs.getTime(i));
                        time = rs.getTime(i);
                        if (time != null) {
                            newRow.add((String) sdt.format(time.getTime()));
                        } else {
                            newRow.add((String) getNullTxt());
                        }
                        break;
                    case Types.TINYINT:
                        newRow.add((Integer) rs.getInt(i));
                        break;
                    case Types.VARBINARY:
                        newRow.add((String) "VARBINARY Type not supported");
                        break;
                    case Types.VARCHAR:
                        newRow.add((String) rs.getString(i));
                        break;
                    default:
                        newRow.add((String) rs.getString(i));
                        break;
                }

                if (rs.wasNull()) {
                    newRow.remove(newRow.size() - 1);
                    if ((getColumnClass(newRow.size() - 1) != String.class) || ( !isUseNullTxt()) ) {
                        newRow.add(null);
                    } else {
                        newRow.add(getNullTxt());
                    }
                }

            }
            rows.add(newRow);

            /*
               We limit the numbers of rows read to the value of maxRows.
               This value is by default set to 10'000 if you set it to 0, 
               there will be no limit.
             */
            counter++;
            if ((getMaxRows() > 0) && (counter == getMaxRows())) {
                break;
            }

        }


    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
        logSqlException("executeQuery()", Level.WARNING, sqlex);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/*
   log a  SQLexception by providing the methode and the Exception
 */
private void logSqlException(String methode, Level level, SQLException sqlex) {
    logger.log(level, "SQL Exception in {0} : {1} SQLState: {2} SQL Error Code: {3}", new Object[]{methode, sqlex.getMessage(), sqlex.getSQLState(), sqlex.getErrorCode()});
    setSQLError("\tSQL Exception: " + sqlex.getMessage() + "\n\tSQL State:     " +  sqlex.getSQLState() + "\n\tError-Code:    " + sqlex.getErrorCode() + "\n");       
}

/*
   log an exception by providing the methode and the Exception
 */
private void logException(String methode, Level level, String message) {
    logger.log(level, "Exception in {0} :  Message: {1} ", new Object[]{methode, message});
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return rows.size();
}

public int getNumRows() {
    return getRowCount();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

public String getColumnName(int column) {
    if (columnNames[column] != null) {
        return columnNames[column];
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

public Class getColumnClass(int column) {

    int type;
    try {
        type = getRsmd().getColumnType(column + 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logException("getColumnClass(" + column + ")", Level.WARNING, "Error fetching column class type, using default String.class. Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        return String.class;
    }

    switch (type) {
        case Types.ARRAY:
            return Array.class;
        case Types.BIGINT:
            return long.class;
        case Types.BINARY:
            return byte.class;
        case Types.BIT:
            return boolean.class;
        case Types.BLOB:
            return byte.class;
        case Types.BOOLEAN:
            return boolean.class;
        case Types.CHAR:
            return String.class;
        case Types.CLOB:
            return String.class;
        case Types.DATALINK:
            return Object.class;
        case Types.DATE:
            return java.sql.Date.class;
        case Types.DECIMAL:
            return java.math.BigDecimal.class;
        case Types.DISTINCT:
            return Object.class;
        case Types.DOUBLE:
            return double.class;
        case Types.FLOAT:
            return float.class;
        case Types.INTEGER:
            return int.class;
        case Types.JAVA_OBJECT:
            return Object.class;
        case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
            return String.class;
        case Types.LONGVARBINARY:
            return Object.class;
        case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
            return String.class;
        case Types.NCHAR:
            return String.class;
        case Types.NCLOB:
            return Object.class;
        case Types.NULL:
            return Object.class;
        case Types.NUMERIC:
            return java.math.BigDecimal.class;
        case Types.NVARCHAR:
            return String.class;
        case Types.OTHER:
            return String.class;
        case Types.REAL:
            return float.class;
        case Types.REF:
            return Object.class;
        case Types.REF_CURSOR:
            return Object.class;
        case Types.ROWID:
            return Object.class;
        case Types.SMALLINT:
            return int.class;
        case Types.SQLXML:
            return String.class;
        case Types.STRUCT:
            return Object.class;
        case Types.TIME:
            // TIME is not correctly rendered
            //return java.sql.Time.class;
            return String.class;
        case Types.TIMESTAMP:
            // Timestamp is not correctly rendered
            //return java.sql.Timestamp.class;
            return String.class;
        case Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE:
            // Timestamp is not correctly rendered
            //return java.sql.Timestamp.class;
            return String.class;
        case Types.TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE:
            // TIME is not correctly rendered
            //return java.sql.Time.class;
            return String.class;
        case Types.TINYINT:
            return int.class;
        case Types.VARBINARY:
            return String.class;
        case Types.VARCHAR:
            return String.class;
        default:
            return Object.class;
    }

}

public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return false;

    /*
     is always false, in this case I do not want to write.. 

     */
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Vector v = (Vector) rows.elementAt(rowIndex);
    return (Object) v.elementAt(columnIndex);
}

/**
 * @return the con
 */
public Connection getCon() {
    return con;
}

/**
 * @param con the con to set
 */
public void setCon(Connection con) {
    this.con = con;
}

/**
 * @return the stmt
 */
public Statement getStmt() {
    return stmt;
}

/**
 * @param stmt the stmt to set
 */
public void setStmt(Statement stmt) {
    this.stmt = stmt;
}

/**
 * @return the connectionEstablished
 */
public boolean isConnectionEstablished() {
    return connectionEstablished;
}

/**
 * @param connectionEstablished the connectionEstablished to set
 */
public void setConnectionEstablished(boolean connectionEstablished) {
    this.connectionEstablished = connectionEstablished;
}

/**
 * @return the rsmd
 */
public ResultSetMetaData getRsmd() {
    return rsmd;
}

public ResultSetMetaData getMetaData() {
    return rsmd;
}

/**
 * @param rsmd the rsmd to set
 */
public void setRsmd(ResultSetMetaData rsmd) {
    this.rsmd = rsmd;

    try {
        // we also set the Values for the JTable Headers
        int noCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        // and now we set the Column Headers and the fieldNames
        columnNames = new String[noCols];
        fieldNames = new String[noCols];
        columnTypes = new int[noCols];
        for (int i = 0; i < noCols; i++) {
            columnNames[i] = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i + 1);
            fieldNames[i] = rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1);
            columnTypes[i] = rsmd.getColumnType(i + 1);
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
        logSqlException("setRsmd(ResultSetMetaData rsmd", Level.WARNING, sqlex);
    }

}

/**
 * @return the counter
 */
public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}

/**
 * @param counter the counter to set
 */
public void setCounter(int counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
}

/**
 * @return the standalone
 */
public boolean isStandalone() {
    return standalone;
}

/**
 * @param standalone the standalone to set
 */
public void setStandalone(boolean standalone) {
    this.standalone = standalone;
}

/**
 * @return the SQLError
 */
public String getSQLError() {
    return SQLError;
}

/**
 * @param SQLError the SQLError to set
 */
public void setSQLError(String SQLError) {
    this.SQLError = SQLError;
}

/**
 * @return the maxRows
 */
public int getMaxRows() {
    return maxRows;
}

public int getMaxRowCount() {
    return maxRows;
}
/**
 * @param maxRows the maxRows to set
 */
public void setMaxRows(int maxRows) {
    this.maxRows = maxRows;
}

public void setMaxRowCount(int v) {
    this.maxRows = v;
}

/**
 * @return the nullTxt
 */
public String getNullTxt() {
    return nullTxt;
}

/**
 * @param nullTxt the nullTxt to set
 */
public void setNullTxt(String nullTxt) {
    this.nullTxt = nullTxt;
}

/**
 * @return the useNullTxt
 */
public boolean isUseNullTxt() {
    return useNullTxt;
}

/**
 * @param useNullTxt the useNullTxt to set
 */
public void setUseNullTxt(boolean useNullTxt) {
    this.useNullTxt = useNullTxt;
}

}
```